# How to understand this summation notation?

Tags: notation

The documentation for OpenCV provides the following [convolution explanation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/filter_2d/filter_2d.html)

> Assume you want to know the resulting value of a particular location in
>   the image. The value of the convolution is calculated in the following
>   way:
>
> Place the kernel anchor on top of a determined pixel, with the rest of
>   the kernel overlaying the corresponding local pixels in the image.
>   Multiply the kernel coefficients by the corresponding image pixel
>   values and sum the result. Place the result to the location of the
>   anchor in the input image. Repeat the process for all pixels by
>   scanning the kernel over the entire image. Expressing the procedure
>   above in the form of an equation we would have:

$$\mathrm { H } ( x , y ) = \sum _ { i = 0 } ^ { M _ { i } - 1 } \sum _ { j = 0 } ^ { M _ { i } - 1 } I \left( x + i - a _ { i } , y + j - a _ { j } \right) K ( i , j )$$
I understand what a convolution is, and how the process works, but I do not understand that summation equation.

Can somebody walk me through how to read it?

For instance, I do not understand where the `Mi` and `Mj` elements come from (as they are not referenced in the write up)

Same for the `ai / aj` elements.

When reading mathematical formulas such as this, how am I supposed to know what they stand for if they are not explained anywhere in the text?

Comment: I'm guessing that $M_i$ and $M_j$ are the number of rows and number of columns in the kernel, and $a_i$ and $a_j$ are meant to account for the location of the anchor point in the kernel, but I don't know why there are subscript $i$s and $j$s in either case. The notation is not explained clearly.